# How to get Block Plugin Id? when block created using block type entity?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have created the Block type entity using Drupal 8 UI. Now I have to Place that block entity programatically in theme region. The related question discussed. 
[Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197013/how-to-place-block-programmatically-in-drupal-8)

As solution given by @Shawn Conn is fine when we define our own block plugin class. As in my case I don't. I created Block type using UI

Answer (score 7):

You use the custom block uuid:

```
'plugin' => 'block_content:' . $custom_block->uuid(),
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's right. I have a block with a UUID of `667863b8-b052-4a3a-8a4e-02e1b0eedea3` and a Plugin ID of `block_content:d199e31a-ff75-4500-b8e0-3de1085a519e`.

Comment: @Beau, the UUID of a block and the plugin id are two different things.